# Application did not respond but no error message on the console

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord bot and added a few slash commands, but when I try tu run one of them, called "info", the bot doesn't respond. The twist is that I didn't get an error message on the console.

Here's my code:

```
info.js

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('info')
            .setDescription('Gets the information about a user or the server!')
            .addSubcommand(subcommand => 
                subcommand
                    .setName('user')
                    .setDescription('Gets the information about a member.')
                    .addUserOption(option => option
                        .setName('member')
                        .setDescription('The user to be selected.')
                        )
                )
            .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
                subcommand
                    .setName('server')
                    .setDescription('Gets the information about the server.')
                    ),

    async execute(interaction){
        if(interaction.options.getSubcommand === "user"){
            const user = interaction.options.getUser('member');

            if (user){
                await interaction.reply(`Username: ${user.username}\nID: ${user.id}`);
            } else {
                await interaction.reply(`Your username: ${interaction.user.username}\nID: ${interaction.user.id}`);
            }

        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand === 'server'){
            await interaction.reply(`Server name: ${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}`)
        }
    },
};
```

index.js

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
// const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const {Client, Events, Collection, GatewayIntentBits} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
});


client.commands = new Collection();

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventsFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventsFiles){
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);

    if (event.once){
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles){
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file)
    const command = require(filePath);

    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command){
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`)
    }
}
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

(I don't know how to format the code here on StackOverflow, sorry.)

As you can see in the `info.js` file, I have a command with two options, with the first one I want to retrieve the information about a given user (or the one who ran the command, if no user is given), and with the second one I simply want to retrieve the server's information, with the member count.

This is my first "post" though, so please give some feedback about making one of these.

Comment: `getSubCommand` is a function, a function will not equal a string and your if statement will never execute the code inside

Comment: @Elitezen So to what should I change it in order to get the code running?
I'm following the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/) to create the code while I'm learning Node.js and the library itself.


**Edit**: I think I found it by myself, I didn't put the parentheses right after the `getSubcommand` function. I'll update this again if it was the problem.

Comment: @Elitezen That was the problem, as I mentioned on the previous comment (edited, btw), the problem was that I did not put the parentheses after the function call. Tysm!